Oidc - Cookies storage instead session storage
I read a lot about this issue and I coudn't figure the right solution for this. I'm using angular-auth-oidc-client v 13.1 and ngx-cookie-service v 13.2.1.
I follow this article https://medium.com/@arv9135/angular-10-spa-and-identity-server-4-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-with-cookie-storage-a572a8baa4ea.
I'm using version 13.1 of Oidc. This has small differences like oidcConfigService.withConfigs instead of "withConfig". So I pass the oidc config in one object but inside of an array. This throw this error: Please make sure you add an object with a 'config' property: ....({ config }) instead of ...(config)
Anyway, I think my biggest problem is about the cookies size. Each one must have a maximum of 4096 bytes and the response of the oidc is an object that exceeds that. It's very similar with this issue that I found but with no solution https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/issues/1437. Can I manipulate the oidc response of session storage so I can save it in cookies with propreties instead of an object? Or another way?
If anyone can help with this I will be very thankfull since I've been in this issue for a few days.
